# One of the table of MySQL database is missing

Tags: mysql

One of the tables of my database is missing. I didn't drop it but it just went missing.

If I make a query on that table of database. It says

> Query 1 ERROR: Tablespace is missing for table courtData.Data.

If I use the command `SHOW TABLES` it shows me all three tables. When I go to the DB folder, It has only 2 files.

The disk size used on the drive is 15GB. I don't have much going on the server other than DB so I am guessing that the db is still there somewhere on the disk.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  There was a big change with 8.0 that makes the investigation of your problem take a different tack.

Answer (score 1):

Not table but tablespace is missing. This means that the file in which table's data was stored on disk was removed (deleted, renamed, moved, made inacessible/nonscannable). Look in the filesystem for it. Try to undelete...

Comment: I searched for it using  'find / -name Data.ibd' but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';
```

But more importantly, has that changed over time?

The table could be in one of 3 places:  `ibdata1`, `Data.ibd` (which you did not find), or a "tablespace".

What version of MySQL?  Have you upgraded?

Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS;`

Does this work?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE Data` ?